# Loading Bootstrap select options through Ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

Using Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap-Select plugin, I am trying to load the options of the select drop down by ajax from database.

The code works perfectly when I remove the `select picker` class from the `select` element but with that class (which is required to use Bootstrap select) it is not loading any of the options.

```
 <select id="arearesults" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="select">Select From The List</option>
 </select>

$('.btn-group .btn').click(function(){
    $.post(
    'con/animalList.php',
    { selType : this.id },
    function(data)
                {
                  $('#arearesults').html(data);
                }
    );
});
```

I already test the Bootstrap select plugin and it is also working in stand alone mode (hard coded). How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Any chance of a jsFiddle to work with?

Comment: I am not sure , Can I use PHP and Ajax there?

Comment: I believe you can use AJAX, but not PHP. You could always fake it somehow. Just need an environment to test and debug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multiple errors in your code.

1. You haven't mentioned the response `data-type` in the `$.post`. Is the response data `"JSON"` or `"html"`, etc?
2. After filling the values through AJAX in the selectbox you have to refresh it.
   Code:

   ```js
   $('#arearesults').selectpicker("refresh");
   ```

Comment: Thanks Coderaemon, I update to code to refresh the selectpicker but I am not sure where to use the data-type in the post? I tried like this way dataType: "html" but it didnt work

Comment: data-type you have to mention in the `$.post` ajax request. Check this https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: I can not get it running for my problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191920/ajax-does-not-work-with-bootstrap-select).

Answer (score 2):

this solution worked for me

```
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({});
```