# AJax does not work with bootstrap-select

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask, flask-wtforms, bootstrap-select

I found [flask-jquery-ajax example](https://github.com/saltycrane/flask-jquery-ajax-example) where the user selects an item from the vehicle "Make" drop down menu, the vehicle "Model" drop down menu is populated by making an AJAX request for a list of models for the make selected.

I tried to replace the drop-down menus by *bootstrap-select* and as soon as I include *class="selectpicker form-control"* in the second drop-down menu it does not get any more populated after the first drop-down has been chosen.

This is the HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Flask Jquery AJAX Drop Down Menu Example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='web.css') }}">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/non-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Select Vehicle</h1>

    <form class="form-horizontal" action="/" method="POST" >
      <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Make:</span>
    {{ form.make(id="make_select", class="selectpicker form-control") }}
      </div>

      <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Model:</span>
    {{ form.model(id="model_select", class="selectpicker form-control") }}
      </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    {% if chosen_make %}
        <h2>You selected:</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Make ID: {{ chosen_make }}</li>
            <li>Model ID: {{ chosen_model }}</li>
        </ul>
    {% endif %}

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
  </script> 
  <script src="/assets/vehicle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the JavaScript [code](https://github.com/saltycrane/flask-jquery-ajax-example/blob/master/fjae/assets/vehicle.js) responsible for populating the drop-down menus:

```
$("#make_select").change(function() {
    var make_id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/models/' + make_id + '/',
    });
    request.done(function(data){
        var option_list = [["", "--- Select One ---"]].concat(data);

        $("#model_select").empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < option_list.length; i++) {
            $("#model_select").append(
                $("<option></option>").attr(
                    "value", option_list[i][0]).text(option_list[i][1])
            );
        }
    });
});
```

Why does *class="selectpicker form-control"* from *bootstrap-select* cause that the second drop-down menu get not anymore populated?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

After AJAX is done, you need to reload the plugin:

```
$('#model_select').selectpicker('refresh');
```

or

```
success: function(data)
{
  $("#model_select").html(data).selectpicker('refresh');
}
```

Comment: Perfect Answer .. thumbs up !!

Comment: but it's not work in ie 10, 11, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28879182/bootstrap-select-drop-list-moves-down-ward-automatically

Comment: Or just $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh'); to refresh all selectpickers on the form.