# JQuery DataTable does not take the styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, datatables

I'm working with AdminBSB - Material Design, when call ajax in the data table to show information with specific style, the data table does not take the styles. When i work with the data table without ajax, it takes the styles fine, but when i use ajax no takes style the input field and select. Why do not the styles take the input and select field? Here's my code:
**JQuery:**

```
//INICIO Data Table Gestión de Solicitudes
$('#search_button').click(function(){
    //console.log("hola");
    var find = $('#find').val();
    var new_find = find.split(' / '); //Consultado (12-2017) en: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711504/how-to-split-the-string-using-jquery-or-javascript
    //console.log(new_find[0]+" ID: "+new_find[1]);
    if(find === ''){
        showNotification('bg-red', 'Debe escribir el nombre o correo del cliente a buscar', 'top', 'center', '', '');
        $('input[id=find]').focus();
    }else{
        data_table.destroy(); //Consultado (12-2017) en: https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3

        data_table = $('.js-exportable').DataTable({ //Consultado (12-2017) en: https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html
            ajax: { //Consultado (12-2017) en: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc
                url: '/minerva/get_request',
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {user_id: new_find[1]},
                dataSrc: function (json) { //Consultado (12-2017) en: https://medium.com/code-kings/datatables-js-how-to-modify-your-returned-ajax-json-data-before-sending-it-to-your-html-table-24a92244bc40
                    //console.log(json.data.documents);
                    var return_data = new Array();
                    //for(var i=0;i< json.length; i++){
                    for(dat in json.data.documents){
                        //console.log(json.data.documents[dat].document_class);
                        return_data.push({
                            //'title': json[i].title,
                            //'url'  : '<img src="' + json[i].url + '">',
                            //'date' : json[i].date
                            //'request_id': json.data.request_id,
                            'document_class': json.data.documents[dat].document_class,
                            'doc_max_pages': json.data.documents[dat].doc_max_pages,
                            'doc_type': json.data.documents[dat].doc_type,
                            'use_type': json.data.documents[dat].use_type,
                            'is_possess': json.data.documents[dat].is_possess,
                        })
                    }
                    //console.log(return_data);
                    return return_data;
                }
            },
            searching : true,
            columns: [
                //{ data: 'id' },
                { data: 'doc_max_pages' },
                { data: 'document_class' },
                { data: 'use_type' },
                //{ data: 'doc_type' },
                //{ data: 'is_possess' },
                //{ data: 'use_type' },
                //{ data: 'is_possess' }
            ],
            columnDefs: [//Consultado (12-2017) en: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html y https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs
                {
                    targets: [ 3 ],
                    data: null,
                    defaultContent: '<div class="col-md-12">' +
                    '<label class="fileContainer btn btn-primary m-t-1 waves-effect">' +
                    '<p style="color: white";><i class="material-icons">file_upload</i></p>' +
                    '<input type="file" class="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload">' +
                    '</label>' +
                    '&nbsp;&nbsp;pdf, jpg, png, jpeg o gif' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-24">' +
                    '<div class="form-group form-float">' +
                    '<div class="form-line">' +
                    '<input type="text" id="file_name" name="file_name" class="form-control" readonly>' +
                    '<label class="form-label">Nombre del archivo</label>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<br/><br/><br/>' +
                    '<div class="col-md-12">' +
                    '<select class="form-control show-tick" id="reception" name="reception" data-live-search="true" required>' +
                    '<option value="">-- Medio Recepción --</option>' +
                    '<option value="Medio 1">Medio 1</option>' +
                    '<option value="Medio 2">Medio 2</option>' +
                    '<option value="Medio 3">Medio 3</option>' +
                    '</select>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<br/><br/><br/>' +
                    '<div class="col-md-12">' +
                    '<select class="form-control show-tick" id="file_type" name="file_type" data-live-search="true" required>' +
                    '<option value="">-- Tipo de Archivo --</option>' +
                    '<option value="pdf">pdf</option>' +
                    '<option value="jpg">jpg</option>' +
                    '<option value="png">png</option>' +
                    '<option value="jpeg">jpeg</option>' +
                    '<option value="gif">gif</option>' +
                    '</select>' +
                    '</div>'
                },
                {
                    targets: [ 4 ],
                    data: null,
                    defaultContent: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-t-1 waves-effect" title="Añadir Página del Documento"><i class="material-icons">add_circle</i></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;0/1'
                },
                {
                    targets: [ 5 ],
                    data: null,
                    defaultContent: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-t-1 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#largeModal_np" title="No Posee"><i class="material-icons">remove_circle</i></button>'
                },
                {
                    targets: [ 6 ],
                    data: null,
                    defaultContent: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-t-1 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#largeModal_bs" title="Borrar Solicitud"><i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i></button>'
                }
            ],
            language: {
                url: '/assets/kavak/minerva/complaints/js/plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/Spanish.json',
                buttons: { //Consultado (01-2016) en: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/flash/copyi18n.html
                    copyTitle: 'Copiado en el portapapeles',
                    copySuccess: { //Consultado (01-2016) en: https://datatables.net/reference/button/copyHtml5
                        1: "Copiada una fila al portapapeles",
                        _: "Copiadas %d filas al portapapeles"
                    }
                }
            },
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'copy',
                    text: 'Copiar',
                    exportOptions: {
                        modifier: {
                            page: 'all'
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'csv',
                    text: 'CSV',
                    //title: $("#title").val(),
                    exportOptions: {
                        modifier: {
                            search: 'none'
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'excel',
                    text: 'Excel',
                    //title: $("#title").val(),
                    exportOptions: {
                        modifier: {
                            page: 'all'
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdf',
                    text: 'PDF',
                    //title: $("#title").val(),
                    pageSize: 'LETTER',
                    exportOptions: {
                        modifier: {
                            page: 'all'
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    text: 'Imprimir',
                    //title: $("#title").val(),
                    pageSize: 'LETTER'
                }
            ],
            pageLength: 5, //Consultado (12-2017) en: https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength
            responsive: true
        });
    }
});

var data_table = $('.js-exportable').DataTable({
    /*columnDefs: [ //Consultado (12-2017) en: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html
        {
            targets: [ 0 ],
            visible: false
        }
    ],*/
    searching : true,
    language: {
        url: '/assets/kavak/minerva/complaints/js/plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/Spanish.json',
        buttons: { //Consultado (01-2016) en: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/flash/copyi18n.html
            copyTitle: 'Copiado en el portapapeles',
            copySuccess: { //Consultado (01-2016) en: https://datatables.net/reference/button/copyHtml5
                1: "Copiada una fila al portapapeles",
                _: "Copiadas %d filas al portapapeles"
            }
        }
    },
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'copy',
            text: 'Copiar',
            exportOptions: {
                modifier: {
                    page: 'all'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            extend: 'csv',
            text: 'CSV',
            //title: $("#title").val(),
            exportOptions: {
                modifier: {
                    search: 'none'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            text: 'Excel',
            //title: $("#title").val(),
            exportOptions: {
                modifier: {
                    page: 'all'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            extend: 'pdf',
            text: 'PDF',
            //title: $("#title").val(),
            pageSize: 'LETTER',
            exportOptions: {
                modifier: {
                    page: 'all'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            extend: 'print',
            text: 'Imprimir',
            //title: $("#title").val(),
            pageSize: 'LETTER'
        }
    ],
    pageLength: 5,
    responsive: true
});
//FIN Data Table Gestión de Solicitudes
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Exportable Table -->
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h2>
                                TABLA GESTIÓN DE SOLICITUDES
                            </h2>
                            <ul class="header-dropdown m-r--5">
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                        <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Acción</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Otra acción</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Algo más aquí</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover dataTable js-exportable">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <!-- <th>id</th> -->
                                        <th>Estatus</th>
                                        <th>Tipo de Documento</th>
                                        <th>Fecha Tope</th>
                                        <th>Carga Documento / Medio de Recepción</th>
                                        <th>Añadir Pág. Documento</th>
                                        <th>No Posee</th>
                                        <th>Borrar Solicitud</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <!-- <th>id</th> -->
                                        <th>Estatus</th>
                                        <th>Tipo de Documento</th>
                                        <th>Fecha Tope</th>
                                        <th>Carga Documento / Medio de Recepción</th>
                                        <th>Añadir Pág. Documento</th>
                                        <th>No Posee</th>
                                        <th>Borrar Solicitud</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- #END# Exportable Table -->
```

Comment: Please see in JQuery code columnDefs {targets: [ 3 ], ....}, the html that is there does not take the style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was very simple. After AJAX is done, you need to reload the plugin, see [AJax does not work with bootstrap-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191920/ajax-does-not-work-with-bootstrap-select)

$('#reception').selectpicker('refresh'); and $('#file_type').selectpicker('refresh');

Also [.selectpicker('refresh')](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh)

After columnDefs[], add this: `initComplete: function(settings, json){ $('.reception').selectpicker('refresh'); $('.file_type').selectpicker('refresh'); },`

The initComplete, can see here [Initialisation complete callback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete)