# Loading Bootstrap select-picker using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a similar problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191920/ajax-does-not-work-with-bootstrap-select) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399676/issue-on-loading-bootstrap-select-options-through-ajax-post). I've tried all the solutions that are described in the comments. And got to a point where it sort of works.

My problem, when I select a option from `#main_cat` the content for `.sub_cat` is loaded the first time (AJAX is loading correctly). But if I select another option from the `#main_cat` the content is loaded but not using the select-picker style. It just shows:

`glyphicon-sort-by-alphabetOPTION 1` (screenshots below)

HTML

```
<select id="main_cat" name="main_cat" class="selectpicker">
    <option selected="-1">Kies een thema</option>
    <option value="Actief_Avontuur" data-name="Actie & avontuur" data-icon="glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet" class="special">&nbsp;&nbsp;Actief, sportief en avontuurlijk</option>
    <option value="Creatief" data-name="Creatief" data-icon="glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt" class="special">&nbsp;&nbsp;Creatief</option>
</select>
<select name="sub_cat" disabled="disabled" class="selectpicker_1 sub_cat">
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('#main_cat').change(function(){
        var $option = $(this).find('option:selected'),
            id = $option.val(),
            name = $option.data('name');
            // open your browser's console log and ensure that you get the correct values
        console.log(id, name);
            $(".sub_cat").empty();
            // call ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",     
            type:'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'my_special_ajax_call',
                main_catid: id,
                main_name: name
            },
            success: function (results) {
                $(".sub_cat").removeAttr('disabled').html(results);
                $('.selectpicker_1').selectpicker(["refresh"]);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I have tried refreshing both `selectpickers` using:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker(["refresh"]);
$('.selectpicker_1').selectpicker(["refresh"]);
```

And this (as was suggested in the question in the link)

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({});
```

Here are some screenshots: The first one is when I select the option for the first time and the second one is when I select another option from `#main_cat`. Do I have to do something with a `foreach` so that I constantly reloads when AJAX is done? Someone know of a solution?

Selecting an option for the first time
[image: Selecting an option for the first time]

Selecting an option for the second time
[image: Selecting an option for the second time]

Comment: `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker(["refresh"]); $('.selectpicker_1').selectpicker(["refresh"]);` remove `[`,`]` square brackets `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker("refresh");
$('.selectpicker_1').selectpicker("refresh");` if still not work also check your console for any errors ?

Comment: Funny, I cant remember using `[`,`]` but I removed them and it didn't solve the problem. and checked console, nothing there.

Comment: put a debug in `success` function did it hit ?

Comment: I've added this `error:function(exception){alert('Exeption:'+exception);}` but nothing?

Comment: Try adding `dataType : "html" ` option to `$.ajax` function

Comment: @elforna, added `dataType : "html",` to the $.ajax function. Did not solve the problem. Still getting the second screenshot when I select another option from `#main_cat`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've used like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "yoururl",
    type: 'post',
    data: {data: data},
     success: function(response){
            target.empty();
            target.html(response);
            target.selectpicker('refresh'); // without the []
    }
});
```

Note that I empty the select, dumbing the response and refreshing after... it worked fine! :D
hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following:

```
.done(function (msg) {
    $("#models_dropdown").html(msg).selectpicker('refresh');
});
```